# User property mappings between local AD, Azure AD and SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, azure-ad

I'm having trouble finding out property mappings from local AD via Azure AD landing in the SharePoint Online User Profile Service.

For example, how would I track down what the equivalent property of the SharePoint Online User Profile Service property "People:SPS-Location" is in Azure AD as well as local AD?

We're using Azure AD Connect to sync user objects to Azure AD which in turn get picked up by the SharePoint Online User Profile service.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of properties which are synchronized into SharePoint Online are outlined at [Information about user profile synchronization in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-SharePoint-Online-177eb196-5887-43c9-84c3-b98a43d35129).

Any property not listed above cannot be synchronized from AD -> Azure AD -> SPO. Instead, you must set up a custom synchronization from AD/AAD -> SPO. There is a sample, [Core.UserProfiles.Sync](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.UserProfiles.Sync) for sync'ing from AAD -> SPO and another sample, [UserProfile.BatchUpdate.API](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/UserProfile.BatchUpdate.API) for sync'ing from AD -> SPO.

Comment: Thanks for the Azure AD -> SPO part. However, I'm still having trouble figuring out the local AD -> Azure AD mappings. I found more info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/user-object-user-interface-mapping), though:

Comment: Here is a complete list [Azure AD Connect sync: Attributes synchronized to Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized).